# Is there a shortcut to open documentation of a given (geometry) node in browser?

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes, shortcut, keymap

Using geometry nodes, I often want to go to the documentation of a given node, to read more about its semantic.

I think I saw a shortcut to open documentation of the current node (eg. [this link](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/output/viewer.html) for the Viewer node) in the browser: what is it?

Answer (score 3):

I found that the shortcut should be `F1`, however it seems [broken at the moment](https://developer.blender.org/T84636).